# How to check if I'm on a custom post type archive in the admin area

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, wp-admin

I am trying to alter the query that's ran on the admin page of my custom post type. This page: /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=my_venue.  Typically, I would use `is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('my_venue')` to check if I'm on the correct page before modifying the query.  However, I have registered my post type with `'archive' => false` so now `is_post_type_archive()` always returns false.

What's the best way to modify the query only for this page?

```
register_post_type(
    'my_venue',
    [
        'has_archive' => false,
    ]
);

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_venue_filters');

function my_venue_filters($query) {
    if (is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('my_venue')) {
        if (!empty($_GET['my_venue_ids'])) {
            $query->set('post__in', $_GET['my_venue_ids']);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are three possibilities, based on the `/wp-admin/admin.php` file:

### Method #1

There are the global `$pagenow` and `$typenow` available:

```
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    if( 'my_venue' === $typenow && 'edit.php' === $pagenow )
    {
        // ...
    }
```

### Method #2

Then there's the current screen, also set in the `admin.php` file with `set_current_screen()`;

```
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( is_a( $screen, '\WP_Screen') && 'edit-myvenue' === $screen->id );
    {
        // ...
    }
```

where we use the `id` property of the `\WP_Screen` object.

If we skim through the `\WP_Screen` class, we find the `current_screen` hook, that might be used instead:

```
add_action( 'current_screen', function( \WP_Screen $s )
{
    if( 'edit-myvenue' === $s->id )
    {
        // ...
    }
} );
```

### Method #3

Then there's the `load-edit.php` hook, that's available prior to the `pre_get_posts` hook:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function()
{
    // Check for the post type here.
} );
```

In this case, the general hook is `load-$pagenow`. No need for the `is_admin()` check here.

### Note

If you're targetting the main query, then you should add `$query->is_main_query()` check as well within your `pre_get_posts` callback.

Also remember to validate the `$_GET['my_venue_ids']` part, it might not even exist in the `$_GET` array.

Nothing new here! I think we've all seen these methods, in one way or another, used in many questions & answers here on WPSE ;-)