# Actions that Run on Admin Edit Page Load After Posts Are Queried

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, admin, actions

What actions run on the edit page in the admin section of a post type?

i.e. xyz.com/wp-admin/edit.php or xyz.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order (custom post type)

I need to run a function when the page loads, after the query has performed to get all of the posts that will be displayed on the edit page.

What action should I use for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What actions run on the edit page in the admin section of a post type

Here are the `do_action` and `do_action_ref_array` calls, for the `edit.php` (post) screen, without any plugins and with a default theme activated:

```
muplugins_loaded - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
plugins_loaded - do_action
sanitize_comment_cookies - do_action
setup_theme - do_action
unload_textdomain - do_action
load_textdomain - do_action
load_textdomain - do_action
after_setup_theme - do_action
load_textdomain - do_action
load_textdomain - do_action
auth_cookie_valid - do_action
set_current_user - do_action
init - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
registered_post_type - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
registered_taxonomy - do_action
widgets_init - do_action
register_sidebar - do_action
register_sidebar - do_action
register_sidebar - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_register_sidebar_widget - do_action
wp_loaded - do_action
auth_cookie_valid - do_action
auth_redirect - do_action
wp_default_scripts - do_action_ref_array
_admin_menu - do_action
admin_menu - do_action
admin_init - do_action
wp_default_styles - do_action_ref_array
admin_bar_init - do_action
add_admin_bar_menus - do_action
current_screen - do_action
load-edit.php - do_action
parse_request - do_action_ref_array
send_headers - do_action_ref_array
parse_tax_query - do_action
parse_query - do_action_ref_array
pre_get_posts - do_action_ref_array
parse_tax_query - do_action
posts_selection - do_action
wp - do_action_ref_array
admin_xml_ns - do_action
admin_xml_ns - do_action
admin_enqueue_scripts - do_action
admin_print_styles-edit.php - do_action
admin_print_styles - do_action
admin_print_scripts-edit.php - do_action
admin_print_scripts - do_action
wp_print_scripts - do_action
admin_head-edit.php - do_action
admin_head - do_action
adminmenu - do_action
in_admin_header - do_action
admin_bar_menu - do_action_ref_array
wp_before_admin_bar_render - do_action
wp_after_admin_bar_render - do_action
admin_notices - do_action
all_admin_notices - do_action
restrict_manage_posts - do_action
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
the_post - do_action_ref_array
pre_get_users - do_action
pre_user_query - do_action_ref_array
pre_get_users - do_action
pre_user_query - do_action_ref_array
in_admin_footer - do_action
admin_footer - do_action
admin_print_footer_scripts - do_action
admin_footer-edit.php - do_action
shutdown - do_action
```

If we include the filters and even if we exclude the `gettext` filter, we get over **five thousand lines!!**. I posted it [here on Github](https://gist.github.com/birgire/08720f8ad8d411445ac8) instead ;-)

> I need to run a function when the page loads, after the query has
>   performed to get all of the posts that will be displayed on the edit
>   page.

I'm not sure what kind of function you need to run, but hopefully you can find your hook with these lists.

You could try for example the `wp` hook, that's fired later then the main `WP_Query` query:

Thanks to @TheDeadMedic for reminding me to target the `edit.php` screen for the `shop_order` ;-)

Here's the updated code snippet:

```
is_admin() && add_action( 'wp', function( \WP $wp )
{
    if( 'edit-shop_order' === get_current_screen()->id )
    {
        // ... your code here
    }
} );
```

I added the `is_admin()` check, since the `wp`hook also fires on the front-end.

You can also check my answer here for other methods:

[How to check if I'm on a custom post type archive in the admin area](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204180/how-to-check-if-im-on-a-custom-post-type-archive-in-the-admin-area/204183#204183)

Comment: I would suggest `load-edit.php`, the clue is in the name: `load-{name-of-current-page}`

Comment: If I understand OP correctly, he was looking for an action that fires *after* the posts have been fetched from the database, for the main query. The `load-edit.php` action fires *before* that. But `load-edit.php` could be a hook wrapper to target the edit.php page. @TheDeadMedic

Comment: Yep, use a function hooked to `load-edit.php` that then attaches all the "real" hooks needed for the request.

Comment: doh, I absolutely agree with you, using it as a wrapper, I thought I had used it here or the screen id, but I forgot to target the edit.php screen, sorry my mind was at another place and another question ;-) thanks @TheDeadMedic

Comment: answer updated, should work now ;-)

Comment: Works like a champ @birgire thank you! (and thank you TheDeadMedic for the suggestion to improve performance by restricting it's running)